# calling to bubbleSort method from main to print sorted array

Tags: java

How do you call to the bubbleSort method from the main method in order to print a sorted list array. I have generated 10 random numbers into an array but I have not figured out how to call to the bubbleSort and print results. What am I missing here?

public class Bubblesort{

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int [] numbers = new int[10];
    //Generate 10 random numbers between 1-100
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        }//end of loop
    System.out.println("The unsorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
         //Solution added
         bubbleSort(numbers); //Call to sort the array
    System.out.println("The sorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

}

```
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] list) 
      {
        int temp;

          for (int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) 
          {
             for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
             {
               if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) 
               {
               temp = list[j];
               list[j] = list[j + 1];
               list[j + 1] = temp;


               }
             }
          }
       }
```

}

Comment: `bubbleSort(numbers);System.out.println("The sorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));`

Comment: You should make your function return the array (list[]) instead of being void. Then you can System.out.println(bubbleSort(numbers))

Comment: Man, talk about missing the obvious... Thank you! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just are not calling your function.

`public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int [] numbers = new int[10];

```
//Generate 10 random numbers between 1-100

  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    }//end of loop
bubblesort(numbers);
System.out.println("The unsorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));}
```

As you see I added the **bubblesort(numbers);** which calls the function you have made. Continue asking questions as I see you are quite new with Java and welcome to the world of coding!

Comment: @bwillo BTW, next to the answers there is a check mark which lets you choose the most helpful answer. By checking it both you and I gain reputation points!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class BubbleSort{
    static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] numbers = new int[10];
        //Generate 10 random numbers between 1-100
          for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int)(rand.nextFloat() * 100 + 1);
            }//end of loop
        System.out.println("The unsorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
        bubbleSort(numbers);
        System.out.println("The sorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] list) {
        int temp;
        for (int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                if (list[j] > list[j + 1]){
                    temp = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[j + 1];
                    list[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```